# Conditional expectation binomial

Tags: probability, expectation

Toss $n$ coins. What is the conditional expectation of the number of heads
given the number of heads among the first x tosses?

I let $X \sim Bin (x, 0.5)$ and $Y \sim Bin (n-x , 0.5)$

where $X$ is the number of heads in the first $x$ tosses and $Y$ is the number of heads in the remaining tosses

I let $Z=X+Y$ so Z $ \sim Bin (n, p) $

I need to find $ \mathbb{E} (Z  \mid $ X=x)

I have tried to apply the formula  $ \mathbb{E}(Z  \mid  X=x) = \sum_{i}z_i  p (z_i \mid x_j)$

But I'm not sure where to proceed.

Comment: I guess one could use formulas, but any gambler can figure it out.  I have $k$ heads already. What is the mean number of heads in the next $n-x$ tosses? Add.

Comment: Your notation may be causing you problems. If you want to use random variables, I would let $U$ be the number in the first $x$ tosses, and $V$ the number in the remaining tosses. We want $E(U+V|U=u))$.